# Identificar o EOF em um DataInputStream

Tags: java, serialização, binary

Estou fazendo um programa que precisa ler um arquivo binário e ir extraindo algumas informações dele, o que tenho até o momento é o seguinte:

```
public void processarArquivo() throws Exception{

    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ARQUIVO DE ENTRADA);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        DataInputStream objectIn = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

        while (objectIn != null)
        {
            try {
                String data = objectIn.readUTF();
                char[]direcaoVento = objectIn.readChar();
                int velocidadeVento = objectIn.readInt();
                int indicePluviometrico = objectIn.readInt();
                float temperatura = objectIn.readFloat();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                objectIn.close();
                objectIn = null;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

O espelho de meu arquivo é esse:

```
Espelho do arquivo DadosMeteorologicos-Exemplo.dat
10/10/2015-E -1-15-19.8
11/10/2015-SE-38-16-15.1
12/10/2015-NW-69-4-15.6
13/10/2015-W -9-3-18.1
14/10/2015-NE-11-14-27.8
15/10/2015-SW-51-0-28.7
16/10/2015-NW-24-0-17.8
17/10/2015-E -11-12-16.1
18/10/2015-E -35-0-26.2
19/10/2015-W -42-8-15.8
20/10/2015-SE-14-17-21.7
21/10/2015-NW-51-0-26.0
22/10/2015-E -37-0-25.2
23/10/2015-SW-9-15-26.1
24/10/2015-NE-2-16-21.9
```

Minha dúvida se refere ao while, existe alguma forma de verificar quando eu chego no final do objectIn? Atualmente eu simplesmente tenho um `while (true)` e espero o programa disparar uma `Exception`. Mas isso me parece errado de todas as formas.

Comment: Parece que é somente capturando uma `EOFException` do while(true) mesmo. Talvez se você adicionar como os dados estão nesse arquivo de entrada, podemos sugerir outra solução alternativa.

Comment: @Articuno Foi como consegui fazer, mas concorda que isso parece "errado"?

Comment: Se a [documentação sugere](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF--), como pode ser errado? Adiciona uma amostra do arquivo na pergunta, caso queira outra opção de leitura.

Comment: Realmente não tinha visto que a própria documentação sugeria isso

Comment: Como é esse arquivo? O tal espelho dá a impressão que ele é textual, com um número variável de linhas e com campos separados por hífen. É assim mesmo ou ele é binário? Se for como falei, fica mais fácil ler linha a linha e quebrar cada uma com um `String.split()`, depois fazer as devidas conversões de cada campo. Me parece que o `DataInputStream` é mais para quando você sabe a quantidade de informações que deseja extrair do arquivo (geralmente binário ou misto).

Comment: @Articuno Suspeito que não é intenção da documentação sugerir usar a `EOFException`. O caso é que um caracter UTF pode ser composto de mais de um byte e a `EOFException` existe para indicar que a leitura dos bytes esperava encontrar digamos dois bytes mas foi interrompida no meio por um `EOF`.

Comment: O arquivo é binário, o espelho é só tentar expor qual é o conteúdo para facilitar na compreensão do código

Answer (score 1):

> Foi como consegui fazer, mas concorda que isso parece "errado"?

Sim, *parece* um pouco errado. Pelo menos pela [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)  do `DataInputStream`:

> ... *An application uses a data output stream to write data that can later be read by a data input stream.* ...

e esse arquivo **não** parece ter sido gerado por um `DataOutputStream`, mas a intenção do `DataInputStream` é ler arquivos no formato gerado por um `DataOutputStream`. O método `readUTF`, por exemplo, exige dois bytes indicando o tamanho do texto, seguido do texto no formato UTF-8 modificado. Da mesma forma, se o tamanho do arquivo não for fixo, é aconselhável incluir o número de elementos no arquivo antes de escrever os elementos. Dessa forma na hora de ler o arquivo, não é necessário detectar o fim do arquivo.

Além disso, arquivos texto normalmente devem ser lidos por uma das classes `*Reader` (`BufferedReader`, `FileReader`, ...) para fazer a conversão de bytes para `char`. No caso acima provavelmente a melhor opção é o `BufferedReader` pois oferece o método `readLine` que retorna `null` para indicar o fim do arquivo.

Outra opção seria usar o `Scanner`, que eu pessoalmente **não** aconselho (sem ter estudado a documentação minuciosamente)

Comment: O arquivo é todo binário, o espelho que coloquei é só para tentar explicar como esses dados se encontram ládentro do arquivo